Unable to exchange short live token for long live token instagram gragh api
i got the access token but while exhangeing it for long live token api getting following error
error: {
message: 'Unsupported request - method type: get',
type: 'IGApiException',
code: 100,
fbtrace_id: 'AnMYrIXYSTKYCA_Sh2qKxkU'
}
const accessTokenApi = {
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                code: code,
                redirect_uri: instagramConfig.callbackUrl,
                client_id: instagramConfig.clientId,
                client_secret: instagramConfig.clientSecret,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            }).toString(),
        };

        const tokenResponse = await this.apiCall(accessTokenApi);

const userPlatform = await this.userPlatformService.getUserPlatfromsByCode(userId, "INSTAGRAM");

        const userLongLiveTokenApi = {
            url:`https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret=${instagramConfig.clientSecret}&access_token=${userPlatform.authToken}`,
            method: 'get',
            headers:{}
        }

        console.log(userLongLiveTokenApi)

        const userLongLiveTokenResponse = await this.apiCall(userLongLiveTokenApi);


It looks like you are missing trying to exchange userPlatform.authToken for a long-living token. However, you first need to update userPLatform.authToken with the value from tokenResponse.access_token. Or, just use it directly in your userLongLiveTokenApi request.
